# Wordpress: Not able to retrieve css for new plugin in admin mode

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm creating a new plugin which will have it's own css file. The css file resides in the root folder of the plugin.

In the plugin section of the admin interface, I have added a few text fields fields. But the CSS is not applied.

I'm adding the CSS file using this code:

```
  // Register styling
  add_action('admin_init', 'event_styles');
  function event_styles() {
    wp_register_style('event_cal', plugins_url('eventcall.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('event_cal');    
  }
```

The following code gives me the CSS path:

```
echo plugins_url('eventcall.css',__FILE__);
```

and outputs

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-eventcal/eventcall.css
```

If I try to enter this URL directly in the browser, it only shows me the front page.

And if I look in the source code using Firebug, where the link to the CSS should be, I only find the entire HTML code for the front page.

Am I using wrong code to use backend in admin interface?
FYI: In my HOST file, I have added `127.0.0.1 mysite.com`

Comment: Did the CSS file actually get to the appropriate path on the server? What you described hints me the possibility of the file not existing at the proper folder on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. A bit embarrassing.
It was a typo - one 'l' to many. Correct name of CSS was `eventcal.css`.

I had no idea that the result would be for the link to load the entire front page. But now I know.